# trying to understand std::cin.get()

Tags: c++, get, std, cin

Hi all so i was reading about std::cin.get() func and read that we use it to capture the newline char that was entered after entering any input to the console. But i kind of got confused while writing a small very basic program and couldn't understand its behavior.

so my program is for the exercise in c++ primer plus. Anyways the code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

void countWords () {
  char word [100];
  char wordDone [] = "done";
  int count = 0;

  std::cout << "Enter words (to stop, type the word done): \n";
  std::cin >> word;

  while (strcmp(word, wordDone) != 0) {
    std::cin >> word;
    count += 1;
  }

  std::cout << "You entered a total of " << count << " words.";

  std::cin.get();
  std::cin.get();  
}

int main () {
  countWords ();

  std::cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

Now here the issue is when i run the above code, the screen gives me proper output but it disappears without waiting for me to enter a return.

But when instead of creating the above countWords() func, if i write the whole code in the main() func, it works perfectly, which is what is confusing me a lot.

As per my understanding, when i enter the char array in console and press return, the buffer keeps the console data and the newline in queue, and after the while loop is processed and the cout is displayed, the return is absorbed by the first std::cin.get(). So then the program should wait for me to enter another return which will then be abosorbed by second cin.get() and also it should ask me another return since there is a cin.get() in main function as well. But for some reason which i am not able to figure out, the output screen just disappears.

Any comments or explanation please??

Comment: You should only have to press enter twice, according to what you described.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would seem you have something stuck in the buffer which is causing all of your `get`s to be filled.

I would suggest the following:

```
cin.ignore(-1, '\n');
```

Comment: The effect of `sync()` is implementation-defined. Try doing `std::cin.ignore(-1, '\n')` instead  which is a more standard-compliant way of discarding characters.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because something is still in your input buffer.

You can add:

```
std::cin.ignore(); // This only skips a single character
```

OR

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // Just to be extra safe. Skips all character in input buffer.
```

Before the :
`std::cin.get();`

Answer (score -2):

cin.get() will return EOF if there are no available characters in the stream and set the failbit of the stream. I am suspecting that is what is happening, so your program will just go through all of your cin.gets and not wait for another return character.

For clarification on how istream::get works:
[istream::get](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/)

Comment: +-1: `cin.get()` will return EOF if the stream has reached end-of-file, which doesn't occur for standard input unless you type Ctrl+D (or your terminal's equivalent). This has very little to do with how many available characters are in the stream buffer (_buffer_, not "in the stream": streams are not containers but flows of data).